# Getting value from JSON

Tags: php

I am struggling to get pull the correct values

I am trying to get the following

packages>items then loop through the ids

```
{"id":1,"title":"Barnsley","slug":"barnsley","packages":[{"id":1,"title":"Group PACKAGE 1","items" 
 {"id":9,"title":"Guiness","band_a":null,"band_b":null,"band_c":null,"band_d":null,"band_e":null,"band_f":null,"band_g":null,"band_h":null,"band_i":null,"band_j":null,"variations":null},
{"id":10,"title":"John Smith","band_a":null,"band_b":null,"band_c":null,"band_d":null,"band_e":null,"band_f":null,"band_g":null,"band_h":null,"band_i":null,"band_j":null,"variations":null},
{"id":22,"title":"Chicken Cheese and Bacon Melt","band_a":4.5,"band_b":4.75,"band_c":5.0,"band_d":5.25,"band_e":null,"band_f":null,"band_g":null,"band_h":null,"band_i":null,"band_j":null,"variations":null}],"additional_items":null,"event_types":null}]}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. The array is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON isn't valid. You're missing two characters `:[` that declare the items array. After fixing the JSON (check it on jsonlint.com) you can iterate over the item IDs like so:

```
$obj = json_decode($str);

foreach($obj->packages[0]->items as $item)
{
    echo $item->id;
}
```

If there could be more than one package you can iterate those too:

```
foreach($obj->packages as $package)
{
    foreach($package->items as $item)
    {
        echo $item->id;
    }
}
```